# Getting legend label on multiple lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer

This question was posted in 2011, and someone has said that QGIS now allows multiple lines for legend entries, but no one mentioned how to do this. I am running wein 2.8.1 and I cannot figure out how to get my legend entry on multiple lines other than manually using text.

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In QGIS 2.8 Composer, there's a Wrap text on option in the Item properties tab when you add a legend which lets you enter a character where you want the new line to start. What I normally do is use the `*` character in the layer's name for where I want the new line. Then input the `*` into the Wrap text option.

*(I'm using QGIS 2.8.2-Wien)*:

[image: Layer names]

[image: Wrap text options]

Comment: Is there an automatic way to do this? I am thinking about taking character count as consideration to wrap labels. sometimes you have hundreds of classes to list in a legend, which makes this approach rather unhandy

Comment: @hilpers - I'm sure you can but it's best to ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as there are probably others who have found a method you're looking for :)

Comment: You can also change the layer display name in the legend settings of the layout to avoid renaming them in the layer panel.

Comment: For automation, look at this answer and my comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449443/203521