# Importing text as legend or to legend in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have a layer consisting of appr. 30-45 classes. The majority of the classes has an item description containing multiple lines of text.
In ArcMap I can achieve a layout like this

[image]

Is a similar layout possible in QGIS 3.8?

I know I can split text in a new line by the means of the 'Wrap text on' option described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/getting-legend-label-on-multiple-lines-in-qgis).

I guess I could replace every line break in my text document with * and set * as my 'wrap text on'-character.
However this is not very convenient in my case. Besides I can't find a way of adding bold font type to the "header/title" of the class. It would be nice if I could generate a "legend text file" (with tags and breaks) in beforehand and then import it to QGIS in some way.

I have experimented with HTML frame, paste in the legend text and add HTML tags for bold text and line breaks. The problem then is to get corresponding legend symbols (patches). It seems like it would demand a lot of manual editing.

I'm looking for a more automated way of doing it. Is there?

Comment: The closest way I can think of is to put only the bold text in the legend. Then put the detailed description in a table, and add that to the layout as an attribute table item. You can duplicate the bold text in the table, or you can place the attribute table next to the legend and manually adjust the spacing in the legend (eg by adding multiple line breaks to each item description using the 'wrap text on' method) until the legend and table items line up with each other.

Comment: @csk, thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a shot even though it's not as automatic as I hoped for. I realise that QGIS so far don't have or support "edit description" like ArcMap. Perhaps in the future?

Comment: If you want a new feature, you can request it here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues. There's definitely room for improvement on the print composer legend.

Comment: @csk, thanks for the link - I've just posted a request.

Comment: Cool. You could answer your own question (including a link to the feature request), for anyone who has the same need. It's useful to know that a feature *doesn't* exist, so they don't waste their time trying to find it.

Comment: @csk. I've tried the attribute table approach, but it's not very convenient as I need the legend to have several columns to fit into the map/paper layout. It's just too much of a hassle in this case. Nevertheless, thanks for your effort and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no edit description in QGIS 3.8. Feature request sent July 30, 2019: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30988